# How to prevent having to rebuild image on code changes

Tags: docker, flask

I started using Docker for a personal project and realized that this increases my development time to an unnacceptable amount. I would rather spin up an LXC instance if I had to rebuild images for every code change.

I heard there was a way to mount this but wasn't sure exactly how one would go about it. I also have a docker compose yaml file but I think you mount a volume or something in the Dockerfile? The goal is to have code changes not need to rebuild a container image.

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
EXPOSE 5000

# update apt
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc wget

# pip installs
FROM python:3.10

# TA-Lib
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

ADD app.py /
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install pymysql
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip freeze >> /tmp/requirement.txt

COPY . /tmp
CMD ["python", "/tmp/app.py"]

RUN chmod +x ./tmp/start.sh
RUN ./tmp/start.sh
```

```sh
version: '3.8'
services: 
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=#########
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=####

  # client:
  #   build: client
  #   ports: [3000]
  #   restart: always

  server:
    build: server
    ports: [5000]
    restart: always
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a multistage build, but nothing from the first stage is being copied to the second stage. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you tell me what part of text? If it is the ubuntu part its because I thought I had to install the ta-lib package with conda for the binary but then found that I would just download it. Just leftover from before. 

Do you know how to prevent needing to rebuild for every change because I think I will have to not use docker if that's the workflow.

Comment: I can suggest a way to do it via bind mounts if you add your docker-compose.yml config to the question.

Comment: Cool cool yeah this is what I have so far... just started learning docker instead of using LXC

Comment: You should use docker for shipping your code. Not for development.

Comment: Yeah well when I went to upgrade to 3.10 for Python it was very problematic on my local and was looking for a quick solution. This whole saga started because I wanted to put a switch statement in instead of nested if else statements. Then there were alias issues and venv issues and it was just too much of a pain in the ass but I still wanted the switch statement that got added in 3.10 lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest to make dev builds faster:

#### Bind mount code into the container

A [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) is a directory shared between the container and the host. Here's the syntax for it:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
  # ... other services ...

  server:
    build: server
    ports: [5000]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # Map the server directory in into the container at /code
      - ./server:/code
```

The first part of the mount, `./server` is relative to the directory that the docker-compose.yml file is in. If the server directory and the docker-compose.yml file are in different directories, you'll need to change this part.

After that, you'd remove the part of the Dockerfile which copies code into the container. Something like this:

```
# pip installs
FROM python:3.10

# TA-Lib
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install pymysql
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "/code/app.py"]
```

The advantage of this approach is that when you hit 'save' in your editor, the change will be immediately propagated into the container, without requiring a rebuild.

[Documentation on syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3)

**Note about production builds**: I don't recommend bind mounts when running your production server. In that case, I would recommend copying your code into the container instead of using a bind mount. This makes it easier to upgrade a running server. I typically write two Dockerfiles and two docker-compose.yml files: one set for production, and one set for development.

#### Install dependencies before copying code into container

One part of your Dockerfile is causing most of the slowness. It's this part:

```
ADD app.py /
# ... snip two lines ...
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
```

This defeats Docker's layer caching. Docker is capable of caching layers, and using the cache if nothing in that layer has changed. However, if a layer changes, any layer after that change will be rebuilt. This means that changing `app.py` will cause the `pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt` line to run again.

To make use of caching, you should follow the rule that the least-frequently changing file goes in first, and most-frequently changing file goes last. Since you change the code in your project more often than you change which dependencies you're using, that means you should copy app.py in after you've installed the dependencies.

The Dockerfile would change like this:

```
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt

# After installing dependencies
ADD app.py /
```

In my projects, I find that rebuilding a container without changing dependencies takes about a second, even if I'm not using the bind-mount trick.

For more information, see the [documentation on layer caching](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/09_image_best/#layer-caching).

#### Remove unused stage

You have two stages in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# ... snip ...
FROM python:3.10
```

The `FROM` command means that you are throwing out everything in the image and starting from a new base image. This means that everything in between these two lines is not really doing anything. To fix this, remove everything before the second `FROM` statement.

Why would you use multistage builds? Sometimes it's useful to install a compiler, compile something, then copy it into a fresh image. [Example](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds).

#### Merge install and remove step

If you want to remove a file, you should do it in the same layer where you created the file. The reason for this is that deleting a file in a previous layer does not fully remove the file: the file still takes up space in the image. A tool like [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) can show you files which are having this problem.

Here's how I would suggest changing this section:

```
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
```

Merge the `rm` into the previous step:

```
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
 tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
 cd ta-lib/ && \
 ./configure && \
 make && \
 make install && \
 cd .. && \
 rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hey Nick I wanted to say thanks for really taking the time here and delivering a hi quality answer. I think the question title on stack overflow should turn up often (a hunch) now I can continue developing on Presidents Day :D. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay tested this out and yes much better... I don't have to rebuild the images which is what I wanted. I suppose at this point is there a way to have something akin to "hot reloading" currently I have to go docker-compose down and then docker-compose up and the changes are shown. If I understand correctly I am simply stopping and restarting the container but if there was a way to do that automatically this would turn me into a Docker afficianado. So if you want to unleash another one of those guys on the world let me know about said "hot reloading" :)

Comment: @MichaelPaccione If you're using Flask, you can enable [debug mode](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#debug-mode) to get hot reloading.

Comment: do you ever stop and consider that you're a wizard?