# source code in host while having docker running it

Tags: docker

I'd like to put a program under some dev environments in docker. I can set up its sdk and run the program with the following dockerfile. However, I would want the source code of the program to live in my host machine since I can use an editor there for code development and testing, and use the docker image for the virtual env running the program. What's a good way of doing this?

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install -y <a list of dependencies>
RUN <script to set up an sdk> # this step creates a /sdk which my program must live in
WORKDIR /sdk

# <repo> contains the source code of my program
RUN git clone <repo> && cd <repo> && <sdk install>
```

Comment: You can do this with bind mounts. See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199701/docker-how-to-prevent-having-to-rebuild-image-on-code-changes/71200183#71200183 Only the first part will be relevant to you.

Comment: I've generally found it works fine to ignore Docker during the development phase; use ordinary host-based tools, a host-based unit-test environment, and so on.  Then add the Dockerfile to the source code repository itself to build an immutable image.  The actual setup for using Docker and bypassing its headline filesystem isolation feature is fairly language-specific; do you have a more concrete example of a setup where you need this?

Comment: thanks guys. `bind mount` is all I need here